# How can I remove all the tracks contained in a folder and its subfolders from my collection with Traktor 2?

Tags: dj, mixing

I imported all the tracks contained a folder and its subfolders into my collection. I now want to remove them from my collection: how can I remove all the tracks contained in a folder and its subfolders from my collection with Traktor 2?

Right now I select manually those tracks in the "All Tracks" list but I'd much rather simply specify the folder to be removed from my collection as it is far less error-prone

I use Traktor 2.6.5, but I am open to upgrade if the feature was added later on.

Comment: Did this problem also get solved with an upgrade to the latest version of Traktor? Or did you figure out another way to do it? If so, you can answer your own question and it would be helpful to future people looking to solve this problem.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I haven't upgraded, still same issue with my version (2.6.5 R250). I prefer not to upgrade unless it solves the issue.

Comment: If your version of Traktor uses NML files to stores track collection information, you should be able to automate the deletion of the entries you don't want using text processing or even XML processing (XSLT for instance) since NML is a Native Instrument XML dialect. The directory containing these files is defined in Setup > Browser > Collection...

Answer (score 1):

According to the TRAKTOR manual chapter "Deleting Tracks" one can delete tracks that are selected.

If the tracks you want to delete had been imported from one folder on a particular date, you may take advantage of sorting by Import Date. The tracks imported on that particular date should then appear in the list consecutively, so that you could easily make a proper selection and delete the tracks.